# SQL Query: Arrange Dates in column in count query

Tags: mysql

I am running a query to get production of group of team per day.

Here is my sample table:

```
Name    Date        Production
1       6/2/2014    5
2       6/2/2014    2
3       6/2/2014    3
4       6/2/2014    4
2       6/1/2014    5
4       6/1/2014    1
3       6/1/2014    5
1       6/1/2014    8
```

This is the results I want to run

```
Name    6/1/2014    6/2/2014
1       8           5
2       5           2
3       5           3
4       1           4
```

Could you help provide me a query?.

Comment: Generally, issues of data display are best handled at the application level, it that's available to you. Otherwise, this is a very basic pivot query of which there are thousands of examples on this site and elsewhere.

Comment: How many different dates would be possible and btw the dates does not look like real date in mysql.

Comment: Hi Abhik, I just need that for 8 dates. But I use it as on when it need. Those are not in My sql format, but those are just given as sample.